# Python Optimal point in a Graph (Pareto Efficiency)

Tags: python, scipy

I have two points. Let us say X(Sales Increment %) and Y(Revenue Increment %) in a graph. Example of points is given below,

```
X = [0.3697, 0.156, 0.1607, 0.1911]
Y = [-0.0213, 0.1801, 0.1550, 0.1401]
```

Hence,

(X,Y) in a graph can be represented by **(0.3697, -0.0213), (0.156, 0.1801)** and so on....

Now I want to write a python code which will pick a optimal point. For example, from the above combination, let us say that the optimal point in an X-Y plane is (0.1607, 0.1550)

So I could conclude that, the optimal sales increment is **16.07%** and optimal revenue increment is **15.50%.** ([Pareto Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency))

I also have the function which establishes relationship X and Y. Which means, for a given X what is Y. So for example, if X is 0.1607 then my Y is 0.1550.

Here is my code below,

```
def lr(x):
    return -(6.940128 - 91.264705 * x + 366.391214 * x ** 2  - 319.256429 *x ** 3 - 383.628503 * x ** 4

from scipy.optimize import minimize
res = minimize(lr, x0 = 0)

res.x

array([-1.10501198])
```

Could you please help me how I could use SciPy package for solving this?

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me yet. How do you define "optimal"? Do you mean the [Pareto-Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency)?

Comment: Yes I mean Pareto Efficiency